# D&D 5e class packs

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

In 5e each class gets a pack. for instance the explorer's pack.

What are in these packs?

What does the pack weight?

Is this pack idea from a previous edition that they just forgot to explain?

Is there any reference for your answer?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the Players Handbook?

Comment: This is a bunch of questions in one question, and the questions are not related except that the answer is 'read the PHB'.  Therefore I am voting to close.  You can ask each of these as a separate question, though I expect all but question 3  will be poorly received.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These packs contain some basic equipment related to your background or class. You can see their price and contents on page 151 of the PHB. Their weight isn't listed, but since you can see everything inside the pack, you can easily calculate it yourself.

Comment: Thank you Eric. You are the only one that thought to tell me where in the player's handbook to look. It seems that everyone else thinks that the PHB is user friendly and that I'm an idiot for not understanding it. (shrugs) Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

[Explorer's pack](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Explorer%27s%20Pack#h-Explorer%27s%20Pack)

- a Backpack - 5
- a Bedroll - 7
- a Mess kit - 1
- a Tinderbox - 1
- 10 torches - 10 (1 each)
- 10 days of Rations - 20 (2 each)
- a Waterskin - 5
- 50 feet of Hempen rope - 10
  total weight = 59

Interestingly, the [Backpack](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Backpack#h-Backpack) says it can hold 30 pounds, but perhaps things tied on to the outside are not included?

> A backpack can hold one cubic foot or 30 pounds of gear. You can also strap items, such as a Bedroll or a coil of rope, to the outside of a backpack.

Still, if we subtract 17 for the bedroll/rope, we're at 42 (the backpack doesn't have to carry itself). Another 5 for the waterskin, and strap the torches to the outside, and we're down to 27.

[Dungeoneer's Pack](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dungeoneer%27s%20Pack#h-Dungeoneer%27s%20Pack)

- a Backpack - 5
- a Crowbar - 5
- a Hammer - 3
- 10 pitons 2.5 (10 x .25
- 10 torches 10 (10 x 1)
- a Tinderbox - 1
- 10 days of Rations - 20 (2 x 10)
- a Waterskin - 5
- 50 feet of Hempen rope - 10
  Total: 56.5
  minus backpack: 51.5
  minus rope: 41.5

If we strap the waterskin to our belt and the torches to the outside, that lowers us to 26.5.

Both of these packs come overloaded, unless I'm miscalculating something. Do we need to strap more things to the outside?

Comment: If I was packing these, I'd probably strap the torches to the pack (don't want that pitch getting sticky all over the inside of my pack and getting all over everything), and the waterskin on my belt. That puts us under the 30 pound limit for both backs.

Comment: good points! I'll update the calculations